# addition on an affine scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

At the Brenner's introduction to the geometric view of the tight closure the author states that an affine scheme has a natural addition (this addition will be extended to the vector bundles). I wonder how is this addition defined? (I, unsuccessfully googled it)

Comment: Can you be more specific as to where this statement is?  Maybe provide a link?

Comment: @Karl, please take a look at: https://de.wikiversity.org/wiki/Kurs:Vector_bundles,_forcing_algebras_and_local_cohomology_(Tehran_2012)/Lecture_2

Comment: Addition is defined on very very special affine schemes - the affine spaces.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, how do we define addition on an affine space? do you mean $Spec(K[x_1,\ldots,x_n])$ by an affine space over a field $K$?

Comment: The addition map is induced by the ring homomorphism from $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ to $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]\otimes K[x_1,\dots,x_n]\cong K[x'_1,\dots,x'_n,x''_1,\dots,x''_n]$ that sends each $x_i$ to $x'_i+x''_i$.

Comment: Yes, it is not defined on affine schemes in general certainly.